# How to optimise a function of binary variables

Tags: c, optimization, binary, genetic-algorithm, numerical-methods

I have a function f(x1,…,xN), where variables xi take only binary values, xi = 0 or 1. I.e. the input space is a space with Hamming distance as metric.
I want to optimise this function numerically and find a minimum.
What’s the best numerical method to get this?

Honestly I don’t know where to start, I never tried to optimise a function of discrete variables, as well as a function of binary variables.

**Note: input space is dimensionally huge (Number of variables is big) so I need the proper numerical method for this kind of problem.**

Comment: Pass an array rather than separate variables. Then you can loop. The minimum is `0` if any of the values is `0`, so you can break out of the loop as soon as you find that value.

Comment: @Barmar i didn’t understand. It’s not obvious that (0,..,0) is a minimum of the function

Comment: @Barmar: They are not seeking the minimum x[i]. They are seeking the point (set of values for the x[i]) for which f(x1,…xN) is a minimum. f is an arbitrary function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil exactly! Thank you Eric

Comment: What is “big”? How many variables are there? Why do you mention Hamming distance—are only certain combinations of input values valid? Which? What is known about the function f? If it is an arbitrary function, the only way to be certain of finding the minimum is to try all input possibilities.

Comment: @Liuuuuk: There is a "genetic-algorithm" tag in this post. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: input space is dimensionally huge (Number of variables is big) so I need a fast numerical method.

Space and speed can often mean different code.

When space is most important, use `bool` for single instances of your *binary variable*  and `unsigned char` for arrays.

When speed is most important, use `bool` for all instances of your *binary variable*.

When variable space is critical, use `unsigned` and encode multiple bits in one `unsigned`.

Comment: Thank you so much! But my question is more focused on algorithm to be used rather then computational implementation.

Comment: @Liuuuuk You did say "Honestly I don’t know where to start,".   To get better answers, post a [mcve], else we are just taking generalities.